# want to remove two .php extension from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to remove 2 .php extention from my url and redirect it to non .php extention.

I want to redirect my url

`http://localhost/pureherb/products.php/rss_feed.php`

to

`http://localhost/pureherb/products/rss_feed`

my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://localhost/pureherb/ [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^know-your-body-type\.php$ http://localhost/pureherb/know-your-body-type [NC,R]

RewriteRule ^health-care\.php$ http://localhost/pureherb/health-care [NC,R]

RewriteRule ^products\.php$ http://localhost/pureherb/products [NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

please help me get resolve this issue

Comment: Are you really sure what you posted is the actual URL you want to redirect? `/pureherb/products.php/rss_feed.php` is a _pretty_ exotic path ...

Comment: Apart from that: what is your actual question? You posted a few rewriting rules without further comment, so we assume those are working and intended. So what keeps you from adding another such rule to achieve what you are apparently looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve your requirement by using capture groups in RewriteRule. Here is the example

```
RewriteRule ^products\.php/rss_feed\.php$ http://localhost/pureherb/products/rss_feed [NC,R]
```

And here is another example (without hardcoding producs and rss_feed):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.php/([^\.]+)\.php$ http://localhost/pureherb/$1/$2 [NC,R]
```

Comment: Both rules raise questions... the first one make completely unnecessary capturing, you can instead hard code that rule which is much more efficient and the second will potentially rewrite other requests as well. To me the question itself is unclear. Which means one should try to find out what is actually asked first, prior to answering ...

Comment: it not working its redirecting to 404 @Rony

Comment: @arkascha, Thanks for your comment. You're right. The first rule had unnecessary capturing. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ashish_more , What response do you get, when you visit the page http://localhost/pureherb/products/rss_feed directly in browser? Is the response successful (e.g. HTTP status code 200) or is it 404?